Block [tag:fees] and in favor of [tag:transaction-fees] and [tag:exchange-fees]
I'd like to block / prevent the use of fees in the general context and retag most of them as transaction-fees or exchange-fees
There are a few questions that relate to Ripple and it's possible to retag them as ripple-transaction-fees
You think this would be a good idea?

It might make things confusing for people that don't understand the difference, but that can be fixed with clear explanations of both tags.

I thought this was a good idea, so I edited the tag wikis, and retagged 10/42 questions.

When is a good time of day to edit these tags?  I'd hate to bury good/new questions with these edits

@makerofthings7 I think the most important factor is staggering out the edits.

Done. I left 2 questions because I didn't feel they precisely fell into either category.

Sure!
Being fees ambiguous, I see no reason to keep it, since we have valid alternatives.
